# the Difference between English Language and Usage and English Language Learners

Tags: discussion, questions

English is my second language, and I have accounts with both **English Language and Usage** and **English Language Learners**.

However, when I look through the questions, my first thought is that they are very similar.

Can anyone help to clarify my confusion?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/tour
http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Hello gaoxinge. The fact that mplungjan has just edited your post above (though 'participate two accounts' is still incorrect) indicates that you should confine your questions to ELL for the time being.

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks. I find it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you.

Comment: Why you did not post this on meta?i would have voted this up.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is ELU intended only for native speakers?

Comment: @starsplusplus How do you deduce that from the comment I made referring to the **basic** mistakes in OP? And since you can't, especially in light of the 'for the time being' qualification in my comment, why address this silly question to _me_?

Comment: I'm not deducing anything. My question was simply that: a question. I wasn't sure of the difference between the two sites, read some meta questions addressing exactly that issue, saw your comment which you sounded like you knew what you were talking about and so asked you to clarify. I assume that from the fact you said it was a "silly question" means that a) the answer is no and b) this is obvious? In which case I'm sorry to have bothered you. :( It did not seem obvious to me.

Comment: (1) The 'for the time being' **obviously** does _not_ mean gaoxinge should not consider asking questions here at ELU in the future (though by definition he will never be a native speaker of English any more than I will of Mandarin). (2) The standard of the grammar used by gaoxinge would indicate that ELL is the more appropriate site at the moment. (3) Some non-native-English speakers have better command of the language than some native speakers; ELL is almost certainly the site they would benefit from (and benefit). (4) This reflects the ethos of the sites.